# git doesn't ask for username and password, no credential helper

Tags: git, github, nixos

#### Problem

I seem to have some weird configuration on my git, where I am unable to authenticate to my repos when in non-root.
When not in root, it refuses to ask for my ids, or use the credentials stored, while everything works fine in root.

#### Additional information

I am working on a private github repos.
My OS is nixos.

#### Checks done

- I have made sure I don't have a system-wide `/etc/gitconfig` (recovered through `git config --system`)
- I have made sure my global configs for both root and non-root matches (recovered through `git config --global` run as root and non-root).
  It only contains my email, username, and the credential helper
- With the `credential.helper=store` in my global configs, and the `.git-credential` in the home directories

  - *as root* it authenticate as expected
  - *as user* it outputs

    ```
    remote: Invalid username or password.
    fatal: Authentication failed for <repos>
    ```
- Without the `credential.helper=store` in my global configs

  - *as root* it asks for my credentials and works correctly once they are given
  - *as user* it doesn't ask for them, and outputs the same thing as with a credential
- This is not a connection issue since I can pull a public repos without any issues as user (but still cannot push to it)
- I have made sure there is no alias for `git` as user
- I have made sure that both user and root reference the same `git` executable (using the command `whereis`, and `where`)
- these problems persist even on new tentative to clone my private repos, or to push on a newly cloned public repos.

#### Questions

Are there other git configurations outside of the `.gitconfig` files in each home directory, the `/etc/gitconfig` and the repos specific `.gitconfig`? [The manual](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) doesn't mention anything else.
My OS doesn't use apt or another classical package manager, and to my knowledge an equivalent to `apt purge` doesn't exist.
My hope is to be able to reset my git configuration and fix the problem this way.

Or do I have no other solution than completely reset my system?

Comment: There are up to four configurations in a repository: /etc/gitconfig (`--system`: may be somewhere else on your OS/build), $HOME/.gitconfig (`--global:` again may be somewhere else), `.git/config` (`--local`), and `--worktree` (relatively new, per-worktree config, normally empty and has to be enabled). There's also `--file` but presumably you're not using that. So it seems like you've found all the right candidates. Note, however, that the `--global` setting depends on the user you're running as, so when you say "as root" and "as user" you'll be getting two different config files.

Comment: For the path to system, I got it from `git config --system`, so I think it should be correct. When I say I checked the global configs, I mean I checked the .gitconfig in both `/home/<user>` and in `/root` (also recovered from calling `git config --global` as root and non-root`)

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you have things set up right. The only other suggestion I have is that maybe `$PATH` for the user and for `root` are different and you're getting different binaries as a result.

Comment: I also thought about this, and I checked the binary paths with `whereis`, they both point to the same one

Comment: Other ideas: something in your environment (`env` command) or a sneaky copy-paste error. Maybe something about how it resolves the helper? (Just throwing ideas at the wall)